# What’s the difference between “Happy with something” and “satisfied with something”?

Tags: meaning

I wonder if there is a difference between “happy with” and “satisfied with”. Are they exactly same?

For example, given sentence: Are you happy with my choice?
But I think it is also okay to say “Are you satisfied with my choice?”

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Do read the FAQ. See also [ell.se]. Good Luck.

Comment: This comes down to the difference between happy and satisfied and that can be found in a dictionary.  But consider that sometimes in a negotiation, one can strike a deal that neither side is really happy about.